# Flutter rebuild only current's location point on map (setState)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, openstreetmap

I am trying to implement user's current location on the map using Flutter and few of plugins (flutter_map, location, etc.) But I have a performance issues probably caused by `setState()` method, which invokes `build()` function every time some value appears in stream.

What I need is to rebuild only one part in the FlutterMap widget, but there are few problems with this. I would normally use separate stateful widget, but PolyLineOptions accept only List of Polyline type.

Here is my code (build function)

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        FlutterMap(
          options: MapOptions(
            center: LatLng(lat, lng),
            zoom: 15,
            minZoom: 14,
            maxZoom: 18,
          ),
          layers: [
            TileLayerOptions(
              urlTemplate: mapUrl,
              subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            ),
   ->       PolylineLayerOptions(polylines: currentPosition),
            MarkerLayerOptions(
              markers: parkingLotsMarkers,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Stream with current location - everytime new value appears, array with marker will update and with this, all widget tree is rebuild aswell.

```
  void _getCurrentLocation() {
    subscription = location.onLocationChanged().listen((l) {
      print("listenin");
      setState(() {
        currentPosition = [
          Polyline(
            points: [LatLng(l.latitude, l.longitude)],
            strokeWidth: 8,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(33, 150, 243, 1),
          ),
          Polyline(
            points: [LatLng(l.latitude, l.longitude)],
            strokeWidth: 30,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(33, 150, 243, .2),
          )
        ];
      });
    });
  }
```

Do you guys have any idea, how to solve this issue? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It may be worth having a look and posting at https://github.com/johnpryan/flutter_map/issues as that type of topic has popped up a few times. I'm a bit surprised at performance issues though, as I'd imagine location would only update max every second or so ?

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look there. Yes and interesting is that even if I click on the button to get one time location Future, app starts to be buggy (mainly when open new page via navigator.